# How to implement a singleton provider for qmlRegisterSingletonType?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to use C++ Classes as Singleton instances in QML and figured that I have to register them with qmlRegisterSingletonType. This function requires a function which provides an instance of the registered C++ class. I am using latest Qt 5.3.1 with included MinGW 4.8 on Windows.

The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType) shows the following example of a provider function:

```
static QJSValue example_qjsvalue_singletontype_provider(QQmlEngine *engine, 
    QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
{
    Q_UNUSED(engine)

    static int seedValue = 5;
    QJSValue example = scriptEngine->newObject();
    example.setProperty("someProperty", seedValue++);
    return example;
}
```

I tried to use this, but I get a compiler warning when I define such a function outside of class scope in a header, occurring in another cpp file including the same header:

```
warning: 'QObject* example_qjsvalue_singletontype_provider(QQmlEngine*, 
QJSEngine*)' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
```

Furtheron, it just feels wrong to write a singleton provider which returns a new instance when called from different cpp files. So I tried an own implementation where I use a static class member to return the instance:

```
// mysingleton.h
class MySingleton: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(MySingleton)
public:
    static QObject *qmlInstance(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine) {

        Q_UNUSED(engine)
        Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)

        if(!m_instance)
        {
            m_instance = new MySingleton();
        }
        return m_instance;
    }
    MySingleton(QObject* parent = 0)
        :QObject(parent)
    {}
private:
    static QObject* m_instance;
};
```

I tried to register this using ...

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<MySingleton>(uri, 1, 0, "MySingleton", 
MySingleton::qmlInstance);
```

This solution doesn't work either, I am getting linker errors:

```
release/main.o:main.cpp:
(.text$_ZN11MySingleton11qmlInstanceEP10QQmlEngineP9QJSEngine[__ZN11MySingleton11
qmlInstanceEP10QQmlEngineP9QJSEngine]+0x42): undefined reference to 
`MySingleton::m_instance'
```

What is the correct solution to provide the required Singleton instance 1) with a function outside of class scope and 2) with a class member function?

Why does the example suggest to create a new instance on every call of the provider function?

Comment: For linker error, the same question is repeated daily (for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10677211/476681)). BTW the description for `qmlRegisterSingletonType` is so poor :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> it just feels wrong to write a singleton provider which returns a new instance when called from different cpp files. So I tried an own implementation where I use a static class member to return the instance

Quote from documentation to [`qmlRegisterSingletonType`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-1) function:

> **NOTE:** A QObject singleton type instance returned from a singleton type provider is owned by the QML engine. For this reason, the singleton type provider function should **not** be implemented as a singleton factory.

It means that such behaviour when singleton type provider returns a new instance is done by intention despite the fact that it, as you have noted, looks weird at first glance. So, your class implementation should look something like below:

```
class MySingleton: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(MySingleton)

    MySingleton() {}

public:
    static QObject *qmlInstance(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(engine);
        Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine);

        return new MySingleton;
    }
};
```

Moreover, you should use ampersand for `MySingleton::qmlInstance` since it is a member method. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18312205/694123) for more info. Then registration should look so:

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType<MySingleton>(uri, 1, 0, "MySingleton", &MySingleton::qmlInstance);
```

Comment: Where in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType) does it say you have to or even can template the call `qmlRegisterSingletonType`?

Comment: @Bob I have update the link to point to a correct method overload.

Comment: A more recent documentation specifies that you can change the ownership of the singleton object to c++ as well:
`NOTE: A QObject singleton type instance returned from a singleton type provider is owned by the QML engine unless the object has explicit QQmlEngine::CppOwnership flag set.`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is (your second example) that you have to initialize your m_instance static member variable. You can do it in mysingleton.cpp file, like:

```
QObject * MySingleton::m_instance = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Qt 5.6 the note in the documentation for `qmlRegisterSingletonType` was updated:

> NOTE: A QObject singleton type instance returned from a singleton type
> provider is owned by the QML engine unless the object has explicit
> QQmlEngine::CppOwnership flag set.

So you can have complete control over how the singleton instance is created.
Here's an example that uses [`Q_GLOBAL_STATIC`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglobalstatic.html#Q_GLOBAL_STATIC):

```
Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(MySingleton, singletonInstance)

MySingleton::MySingleton(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(this, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
}

MySingleton *MySingleton::instance()
{
    return singletonInstance();
}

QObject *MySingleton::qmlInstance(QQmlEngine *, QJSEngine *)
{
    return MySingleton::instance();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to call this singleton class also from c++ please change the line

```
return new MySingleton;
```

to:

```
return new &MySingleton;
```

Comment: I never saw the second code snippet in real code. What does this actually do?